# Example environment

Tags: environments, examples

I want an example environement that put Example 1.2 in the margin (bold) Text of example in the textwidth, Solution in the margin (italics) and the text of solution in the text width.

Comment: What are you planning to do about it?

Comment: Write maths notes or books

Comment: Can I add a picture to my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution 1

Here's something to get you going using the [`ntheorem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ntheorem) package.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}   % needed for theorems, examples- MUST load AFTER amsmath
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{margincmh}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{##1 ##2}]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{##1 ##2} -- ##3\theorem@separator\hskip\labelsep]}%

\newtheoremstyle{margincmhsoln}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{##1}]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{##1} (##3): ]}%
\makeatother

% example
\theoremstyle{margincmh}
%\theorembodyfont{\itshape}}
\theorembodyfont{}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremprework{\medskip}
\theorempostwork{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{myexample}{example}

% solution
\theoremstyle{margincmhsoln}
\theorembodyfont{}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theoremprework{\medskip}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{mysolution}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{myexample}
\begin{mysolution}
 \lipsum[2] 
\end{mysolution}
\end{document}
```

## Solution 2

Alternatively, if you'd prefer to make the environment yourself without a theorem package, you can create it as a simple `list`- I have used the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package to help with the margins

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{myexample}
\newenvironment{myexample}{\refstepcounter{myexample}\itemize[leftmargin=0mm]\item[\bfseries example \themyexample]}{\enditemize}

\newenvironment{mysolution}{\itemize[leftmargin=0mm]\item[\itshape Solution]}{\enditemize}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{myexample}
\begin{mysolution}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mysolution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro glad it helped! if you feel that my answer has been useful, you can feel free to upvote it using the arrows- this gives me reputation, which is the currency of the site :) if it answers the question completely to your satisfaction, you can consider accepting my answer using the green mark (but you might like to wait a day or so in case any other answers appear) :)

Comment: If I have large outer margins (even and odd pages) how I can realise this correctly in both pages?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possibility with [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = section ,
  headings = margin ,
  counter-format = se.qu
}

\RenewQuSolPair
  {question}
  {solution}[print][headings-format=\itshape]

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[1]  
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[2] 
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hiding the number of the solution is possible but requires a little bit more work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{margin-no-nr}{default}{
  runin = true ,
  title-post-code = \space ,
  attach = { main[l,vc]title[r,vc](0pt,0pt) }
}

\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = section ,
  counter-format = se.qu
}

\RenewQuSolPair
  {question}[name=Example][headings=margin]
  {solution}[print][headings=margin-no-nr,headings-format=\itshape]

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[1]  
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[2] 
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My Textstudio dont charge \usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}

Comment: You probably mean _TeXstudio_ which is an _editor_ and not a TeX distribution. The first public version of `exsheets` on CTAN was `2012/10/05 v0.2` so this probably means that your TeX distribution is outdated.